# How to write to file in C

Tags: c

I have a program I am working on that will start and stop a servo. I can issue the following command from the command line and it works. `echo 2=120 > /dev/servoblaster` that will start the servo in motion. Now I have the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;


   fp = fopen("/dev/servoblaster", "w");
   if (fp == NULL) {
       printf("Error opening file\n");
       exit(0); 
 }
   fprintf(fp, "2=120");
   fclose(fp);
   fflush(fp); 
   return 0;
}
```

But when I execute it nothing happens, now when I try the `echo 2=120 > /dev/servoblaster` command it will say `Bad input: 2=1202=120` but if i repeat the same `echo 2=120 > /dev/servoblaster` command it will work again. If i was to try and execute my above program 3 times the output when I try to execute the `echo` command its output will be `Bad input 2=1202=1202=120 2=120` so to me it seems like the file is not finished being written to in my program. Can someone point out if I am missing something?

Comment: `fflush(fp)` can't be done after `fclose(fp)` because after closing the pointer is no longer valid. You should swap the two calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a newline after the command, like `echo` does:

```
fprintf(fp, "2=120\n");
```

Presumably, the servo's driver waits until it sees a newline before acting on a command.

Answer (score 0):

the program has no problem, I run the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("/home/syler/servoblaster", "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        exit(0); 
    }   
    fprintf(fp, "2=120");
    fclose(fp);
    fflush(fp); 
    return 0;
}
```

the result is

```
cat /home/syler/servoblaster
2=120
```

so, there must be the "servoblaster" kernel driver module problem.

Comment: Thanks nneonneo, I modify the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but I just ran into the same problem so am posting what I know.  From what I'm seeing, the "\n" is needed, however that screws up the buffer for the next time (i.e. it puts a "\n" into the buffer so your next write appears to be bad data even if it's good data).  My current work around is to put a "\n" before and after the string.  This ensures it works every time, but I always get a "Bad Data" message due to the "\n".  Still searching for the correct way to do this but haven't yet found a call from C to get this code working.

Answer (score -3):

This work fine for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("/home/syler/servoblaster", "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        exit(0); 
}   
fprintf(fp, "2=120");
fprintf(fp, "\n");
fclose(fp);
fflush(fp); 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why you answer to a 2 years old question without add anything new?

Comment: no, i did add this line "fprintf(fp, "\n");" to solve that "\n" problem.

Comment: Ok... I mean you didn't add anything new respect other answers and respect the accepted one.